# 2 Way SSL using Apache - Certificate questions

Tags: apache, security, authentication, ssl

I've been googling like mad trying to figure this out, but the answer doesn't seem to be clear, or at least, it seems like there are contradictory answers.

I'm tasked with setting up an Apache web server with 2Way SSL authentication. We use verisign to get our certificates, so we have a certificate for the web instance with the correct hostname details, signed by verisign, and an intermediate certificate from verisign. This all works very well.

Now, we need to set up a 2Way SSL connection. The initial expectation is that the client will manage their own certificates, and provide them to us for authentication. More than one client may be connecting, and they should each have access to different resources when they connect.

From what I've read, I'm not sure how this would be done...

This is a pretty good overview, but in this situation, they are using self-signed certificates: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34897/configure-ssl-mutual-two-way-authentication

Using these details, it would seem like we would have to make the trusted CA point to the certificate authority that signs the client's certificate.

Is it possible to use the client certificate as the trusted CA (even though it isn't self signed, but signed by a CA) or would we have to put a trusted CA from their signer (and at that point, would a CA bundle that includes all the client certificate authority CAs work?) on the server and then use the SSLRequire statements to limit access to specific details of the certificate?

As a followup, can we use the SSL Certificate that we get from verisign to sign client certificates?

Comment: Nevermind the followup, I've found documentation that indicates that the certificates verisign issues can't be used to sign other certificates (which makes sense)

Comment: Verisign will not sell you a certificate you can use for signing other certificates. You just need to tell mod_SSL where to find the public part of the ca cert used to sign the client certs. If you are using a reputable ca then this certificate is probably already installed, but since you've told us NOTHING about what Apache is running on nor where you installed it from, we can't tell you where that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after several more hours on google, and some testing, I was able to figure out what I needed to.

If I want to use a certificate signed by verisign or some other public CA, I would have to copy their public intermediate certificate (the one that they use to sign the client certs) to my server and specify it as the SSLCACertificateFile in the configuration. The caveat is that then *any* cert signed by that CA would be accepted, and that's where the SSLRequire directives can used to narrow that down to specific certificates.

Using the SSLVerifyClient optional_no_ca directive would make it assume that the cert is trusted, even if it isn't, and then I would have to use SSLRequire directives to verify the details are correct, however, anybody could create and sign their own certificate with those details and there would be no way to tell.

Creating my own self signed CA certificate, and then using that to sign the client certificates and issuing them to the clients is the only way to both ensure that the cert isn't a forgery and not requiring SSLRequire directives to ensure that only the people that I specify can connect.

Please comment/correct me if I'm wrong on any of this.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
SSLVerifyClient optional_no_ca
```

In your Apache config. This will request the client certificate but not validate it against a CA. It will then be up to your local script to examine the resulting environment variables set by Apache such as 'SSL_SERVER_S_DN' and decide whether to allow the request or not.

These mod_ssl environment variables are also what your code needs to look at when determining what resources the client can access.

The full documentation is here [mod_ssl](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html) although you probably found that already.

A note on client certificates. If you did want to use a CA and leave it to the clients, they may all use different CA's and you would have a job maintaining them all on your server. It would be much better to trust a single CA.

The advantage would be that then you could use the build in SSL support to do all your certificate checks and not write your own solution.

You could enforce a single CA by specifying an on-line provider and using email signing certificates to identify clients. These would work fine, just the Certificate Subject would be an email address instead of a domain name.

Or you could set up your own CA and sign client certificates yourself. This is not too difficult and gives you complete control. Either route would require you to add the CA root certificate (plus intermediates) to a file Apache can read and point 'SSLCACertificateFile' to it.

Comment: Using this method anyone can create a certificate claiming to be anybody and your webserver/application will be none the wiser.

Comment: You mean the first part - if the CA is not checked. Then yes - I was trying to answer the question of how self signed certs would work. It would be up to the code to decide whether the trust the incoming certificate. Anybody who knew what the code was looking for could create a certificate with the same details and sign in as well.